# Procedure or function usp_employee_update has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm using a stored procedure to update my two tables:

`employees` and `useraccounts`
However, whenever I update the table I get this error

> Procedure or function usp_employee_update has too many arguments specified.

I'm using a devexpress gridview. I update my table under the rowupdating event

My SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="users" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WaterBillingConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT UserAccounts.UserID, Employees.FirstName, Employees.MiddleName, Employees.LastName, Employees.ContactNumber, UserAccounts.UserName, UserAccounts.Password, Ref_UserTypes.UserTypeCode FROM Employees INNER JOIN UserAccounts ON Employees.EmployeeID = UserAccounts.PersonID INNER JOIN Ref_UserTypes ON UserAccounts.UserTypeID = Ref_UserTypes.UserTypeID" UpdateCommand="usp_employee_update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="fname" SessionField="fname" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="lname" SessionField="lname" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="mname" SessionField="mname" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="contact" SessionField="contact" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="id" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="uname" SessionField="uname" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="password" SessionField="password" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="uid" SessionField="uid" />
     </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_employee_update]
@fname varchar(50),@lname varchar(50), @mname varchar(50),@contact 
decimal(11,0), @id integer, @uname varchar(50), @password varchar(50), @uid 
integer  
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE       Employees 
SET                FirstName = @fname, LastName = @lname, MiddleName = 
@mname, ContactNumber = @contact
from Employees a join UserAccounts b on a.EmployeeID = b.PersonID 
WHERE        (UserID = @id)

UPDATE       UserAccounts
SET               UserName = @uname, Password = @password, UserTypeID = @uid
from Employees a join UserAccounts b on a.EmployeeID = b.PersonID 
WHERE        (UserID = @id)
commit

END
```

RowUpdating

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = e.Keys[0].ToString();
        Session["fname"] = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
        Session["mname"] = e.NewValues[2].ToString();
        Session["lname"] = e.NewValues[3].ToString();
        Session["contact"] = e.NewValues[4].ToString();
        Session["uname"] = e.NewValues[5].ToString();
        Session["password"] = e.NewValues[6].ToString();
        Session["uid"] = e.NewValues[7];

    }
```

gridview

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="users" KeyFieldName="UserID" OnRowUpdating="ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating" style="font-size: large" Theme="MetropolisBlue" Width="100%">
                         <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="OnCustomButton" />
                         <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="True" />
                         <Templates>
                             <DetailRow>
                                 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="logtrail" KeyFieldName="LogID" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="ASPxGridView2_BeforePerformDataSelect" style="margin-top: 0px" Theme="MetropolisBlue" Width="100%">
                                     <Columns>
                                         <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LogID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                                             <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                                         </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                         <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LogTrail" VisibleIndex="1">
                                         </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                         <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="LogDate" VisibleIndex="2">
                                         </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
                                     </Columns>
                                 </dx:ASPxGridView>
                                 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="logtrail" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WaterBillingConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [LogID], [LogTrail], [LogDate] FROM [LogSessions] WHERE ([UserID] = @UserID)">
                                     <SelectParameters>
                                         <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="userid" Type="Int32" />
                                     </SelectParameters>
                                 </asp:SqlDataSource>
                             </DetailRow>
                         </Templates>
                         <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True" />
                         <Columns>
                               <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowEditButton="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                                        <CustomButtons>
                                                <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btnDetails" Text="New" >
                                                </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                                                  </CustomButtons>
                                             </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>

                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UserID" ReadOnly="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FirstName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="MiddleName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LastName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ContactNumber" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UserName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="6">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Password" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="7">
                             </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                             <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="UserTypeCode" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="8">
                                 <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" TextField="UserTypeCode" ValueField="UserTypeID">
                                 </PropertiesComboBox>
                             </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                         </Columns>
                     </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I see that you're not defining fixed data types for each `SessionParameter` inside `UpdateParameters` section, also some values with wrong types assigned in `RowUpdating` event that promptly trigger "too many arguments".

First, you need to set data type on `SessionParameter` exactly matches with data types defined in stored procedure parameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="users" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WaterBillingConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT UserAccounts.UserID, Employees.FirstName, Employees.MiddleName, Employees.LastName, Employees.ContactNumber, UserAccounts.UserName, UserAccounts.Password, Ref_UserTypes.UserTypeCode FROM Employees INNER JOIN UserAccounts ON Employees.EmployeeID = UserAccounts.PersonID INNER JOIN Ref_UserTypes ON UserAccounts.UserTypeID = Ref_UserTypes.UserTypeID" UpdateCommand="usp_employee_update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="id" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="fname" SessionField="fname" Type="String" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="mname" SessionField="mname" Type="String" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="lname" SessionField="lname" Type="String" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="contact" SessionField="contact" Type="Decimal" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="uname" SessionField="uname" Type="String" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="password" SessionField="password" Type="String" />
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="uid" SessionField="uid" Type="Int32" />
     </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

NB: If you're not sure, add `DbType="Int32"`, `DbType="String"` or `DbType="Decimal"` for each `SessionParameter` depending on parameter data types.

Second, assign all session parameter values depending on predefined data type above:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    Session["id"] = e.Keys[0]; // int
    Session["fname"] = e.NewValues[1].ToString(); // String
    Session["mname"] = e.NewValues[2].ToString(); // String
    Session["lname"] = e.NewValues[3].ToString(); // String
    Session["contact"] = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValues[4]); // decimal
    Session["uname"] = e.NewValues[5].ToString(); // String
    Session["password"] = e.NewValues[6].ToString(); // String
    Session["uid"] = e.NewValues[7]; // int
}
```

PS: Use `Convert.ToInt32` (`int.Parse`) or `Convert.ToDecimal` (`decimal.Parse`) for string values stored in `e.Keys` or `e.NewValues` array/indexer if parameter data type defined as `int` or `decimal` respectively.

Afterwards, the `SessionParameter` binding should works.

Comment: Have you tested that stored procedure is working in SSMS? If it's working, then either the gridview or `SqlDataSource` causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.. it works in SSMS. But when I refresh my paramaters, a RETURN_VALUE direction parameter pops up. Should I set its value in the row_updating event?